# Session data not retaining in Ajax requests to https

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, yii

On my localhost I am making an ajax call to a url which is on https i.e. from http://localhost/MySite to https://localhost/MySite/user/register. So basically I am doing ajax request from http to https. To avoid CORS error I have also set following header.

$accessControlAllowOrigin = 'http://localhost';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $accessControlAllowOrigin");

Now on the first Ajax request I am setting some data in Session. But on the subsequent Ajax requests, I am not getting that Session data.Also when I print session id for the first & subsequent requests, they are different.
So I am not able to access session data in the later requests. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: had you sent Https request to same server?

Comment: yes I am making requests to same url. And i am doing this on localhost.

Comment: Please some your code.